# Словарь python и передача ключа

Tags: python, словари, dict

Я хочу создать словарь, в котором значением будет объект - лямбда функция, вызываемая от своего же ключа
т.е. `dict[1]()` вызовет лямбда функцию от 1 итд.
Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как передать именно этот ключ функции, например, если буду в цикле складывать в словарь `dict[key]=lambda: key+1`, то в итоге для всех элементов будет вызываться функция с последним значением ключа

Answer (score 3):

Надо добавить не обязательный аргумент равный `key`

```
dict_ = {} 

for key in range(5):
    dict_[key] = lambda key=key: key + 1
```

В одну строку

```
dict_ = {key: lambda key=key: key + 1 for key in range(5)}
```

Answer (score 2):

В качестве альтернативы

```
d = {}

for k in range(10):
  d[k] = (lambda k: lambda: k + 1)(k)

print(d[0]()) # 1
print(d[3]()) # 4
```

Но использование параметра со значением оп умолчанию предпочтительнее