# coздание кнопок через цикл c разными аргументами передаваемыми в команду

Tags: python, циклы, tkinter

Хочу создать список кнопок из имеющегося списка элементов.
Но не могу понять почему аргумент команды ко всем кнопкам присваивается значение последнего элемента

```
 command=lambda: self.add_button_clicked(i.get_position()))
```

полный код блока:

```
 buttons_list = list()
 for i in self.__position_list.get_position_list():
     b = tk.Button(frame_button, text=i.get_name(), width="15", command=lambda: 
                                                self.add_button_clicked(i.get_position()))
     b.grid()
     buttons_list.append(b)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Словарь python и передача ключа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201555/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c-python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно передать `i` в `lambda`:

```
b = tk.Button(frame_button, text=i.get_name(), width="15",
              command=lambda i=i: self.add_button_clicked(i.get_position()))
```